# python: input is not matching

Tags: python, input

```
import os
import fileinput

filenames1=os.listdir("./chi_square_metal_region_1")
filenames1.sort()

for line in fileinput.input("./test_input.dat"):
    for eachfile in filenames1:
        if eachfile == line:
            print yes
```

I don't get any errors when I run this code, but it's not printing 'yes', which is the expected output.

It should print 'yes' twice as I there are two files in input which match with `eachfile`. Why is it not printing the expected output?

Comment: what are the contents of `filenames1`, and the contents of `test_input.dat`?

Comment: If this code ever got to the last line, it would raise `NameError`.

Comment: There are 2000 files in filenames1 and there are two lines in test_input.dat. File names are like 1000.dat, 1250.dat etc. I typed two file names 4000.dat and 4500.dat in test_input.dat in two lines. These two files exists in filenames1.

Comment: You need to surround the `yes` with quotation marks.

Comment: using "yes" is not working.

Comment: You have to put that input file into a list and do someyhing like `if eachfile in list: print "yes"`

Comment: I am still trying but not working. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
for line in fileinput.input("./test_input.dat"):
```

the variable line will contain '\n' at the end. Try this:

```
import os
import fileinput

filenames1=os.listdir("./chi_square_metal_region_1")
filenames1.sort()

for line in fileinput.input("./test_input.dat"):
    for eachfile in filenames1:
        if eachfile == line[:-1]:
            print yes
```